# Javascript working in JSFiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lkseosw/1/) works with the javascript I've written, and it also works in stackoverflow's version of the snippet tool, but when I try to run it straight from my computer or from Cloud 9's ide it doesn't want to work.

Because if I include the javascript in stackoverflow's section for javascript it will work, I've included it on http://augie.cf/ It's the same exact script though, line for line.

When you click one of the radio button it should console log which button you clicked on. This works in JSFiddle like I said, but not anywhere else.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://augie.cf/stackoverflow/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a id="advSearch" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Advanced Search</a>    

<!-- Advanced Search Popup -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Begin Popup content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Advanced Search</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="radio-buttons">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" id="or" value="or" name="radio">Or</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" id="and" value="and" name="radio">And</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Modal content -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Advanced Search Popup -->
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated. This is driving me mad!

Comment: Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`

Comment: In `JSFiddle`, script is interpreted `onload` by-default...

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. In a similar environment, I use $(document).ready and it still doesn't function. I'll look into it further and update my question if need be. Thank you.

Comment: Just checked it out in my original DOM as I made this for troubleshooting, and I was incorrect. That section of JS was outside of $(document).ready I must have taken 3 hours trying to figure out what the problem was. Thanks a billion.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_